# Errors in forms with bootstrap - Symfony 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to implement bootstrap styles when the form has errors, and I have succeeded ... but in a very tedious way.
For example:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.name) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
</div>
```

When there is an error in the form, I would like to add the "has-danger" class to the corresponding divs to customize the view. In this way it would be like this:

```
<div class="form-group has-danger">
    {{ form_label(form.name) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
</div>
```

I have come up with a not very pretty way to do it:

```
<div class="form-group {% if form.name.vars.errors|length > 0 %}has-danger{% endif %}">
```

The problem is that I would have to add this code to all the fields of all the forms on my website, which I do not see well.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at [form themes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes) as they already integrate Bootstrap CSS. Most probably you just need to use `bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig` instead of `form_div_layout.html.twig` as form theme in `config/packages/twig.yaml`:

```
twig:
    ...
    form_themes:
        - bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig
```

If that's not enough you can customise each fragment of the forms as you prefer and then use it in your forms. More aspects and info in the same section of the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#twig).